# How can I upload a folder with images

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, multer

I'm using Node.js with express and multer for manage a single file upload.
But I would like to be able to upload a folder which contains for example 10 images inside.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();

//settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);

//middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: 'files/',
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})

app.use(multer({
  storage: storage
}).single('avatar'));
```

[image]

Folder that I would like to upload to my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();

//settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);

//middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: 'files/',
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})

app.use(multer({
  storage: storage
}).array('avatar',100));//This will allow up to 100 images
```